# How do I use the "Setup Tracking Scene" feature with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, tracking

I'm trying to use the *Setup Tracking Scene* button(in the Movie Clip Editor) with Cycles. While it works fine in Blender Internal, when I switch it to Cycles, I don't get shading or shadows. Is the setup for compositing in Cycles different from Blender Internal?

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot of the Cycles render?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is different. I believe that for cycles you don't have directly a "shadow only" material. You have to do some tricks in material settings(with the node editor).

Comment: perhaps you would like to elaborate on these tricks?

Comment: You may be able to use some of the stuff in properties>object>ray visibility