# Imported .3ds models when rendered become transparent

Tags: rendering, import

When I import a .3ds model and render in front of an image it is transparent and loses its material.  What an I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of your issues lies within the *Render Layer* options. You need to have no mask layers, and you need to move the objects to separate layers. To disable the transparency of the background you can go to *Render Settings > Film* and un-tick the *Transparent* checkbox.

[image: Transparent]

Feel free to comment if I have not addressed your issue, your question is rather vague.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The .3ds objects are in the foreground and when rendered they become transparent.  I unchecked the transparent box and the background image disappeared.

Comment: OK, never mind, try removing the *Mask* layers in your Render Layer settings

Comment: Still there @Mark?

Answer (score 1):

You have some [compositing nodes](http://lender.org/manual/composite_nodes/index.html) which appear to have been added by the *setup tracking scene* button in the motion tracker. Note that AFAIK this setup doesn't work with cycles out of the box, see [How do I use the "Setup Tracking Scene" feature with Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/832/599)

You also have two separate [renderlayers](http://blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html), one of which is blank because it is masking itself. It's a bit hard to say how it should be without knowing more about what you are trying to do, but you can at least prevent the render from "disappearing" by connecting the background renderlayer straight into the output:

[image]

I suggest you read/watch some tutorials on renderlayers and compositing :)